# MySQL Backup and Restore using mysqldump.exe and mysql.exe

Tags: java, mysql

how to include `mysqldump.exe` and `mysql.exe` in the current package and give it's name to backup or restore rather than passing a path like following.

```
String command = "D:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysqldump -uroot -pdbpass --add-drop-database -B db........
```

in c# we can do this using '`ProcessStartInfo`'

Comment: you shouldn't i think it required other files in bin folder

Comment: can u tell me how to do it without getting the mysqldump.exe or mysql.exe file path

Comment: you should get the path but no need to include in your package

Comment: Have a look at `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Why? You can perform and indeed schedule backups directly in MySQL. No Java required at all.